# Add a hyperlink by the side performance point scorecard

Tags: sharepoint-designer, hyperlink, performancepoint, dashboard-designer-2013

I am using PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer for SharePoint 2013. Data are coming from SSAS 2012 cube. Is it possible to add a **hyperlink** (Summary) by the side of Scorecard's title?
I tried to edit the dashboard page via SharePoint designer but it did not work.

The figure below explains what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Fig 1: Original Scorecard

[image]

Fig 2: Scorecard with a hyperlink by the side of its title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, rather than having a separate URL besides the title, I used Title URL for the web part that hosts scorecard. So in the above figure at the top, if I click **Kathmandu Valley Project**, it will take me to the desired SharePoint page.

Below are the steps required to edit the Title URL of the web part.

1. Click edit web part.
2. Expand Advanced section.
3. Fill in the value for Title URL.

It did gave me an alternative way to achieve my purpose to redirect to the summary page from the scorecard.